# Cloudflare 525 error code and port scan

Tags: linux, denial-of-service

Today, Cloudflare return code 525 for some https connections.
And I see many connections in iftop on the origin server. This connections - port scan.

I used iptables, and block all packets, not from 22, 80, 443 ports, but sometimes I get 525 code from Cloudflare anyway.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check [Cloudflare Status](https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/) and [DownDetector](https://downdetector.com/status/cloudflare/map/), There was an [outage caused at Cloudflare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-outage/) itself, a few days ago.

Second, Cloudfalre provides documentation on [Fixing Error 525: SSL handshake failed](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-525-ssl-handshake-failed/44256), e.g.

- Make sure you have a valid SSL certificate installed on your origin server.
- Check with your hosting provider to make sure they’re listening on port 443.
- Check to make sure your origin server is properly configured for SNI.
- Be sure the cipher suites your server uses match what is supported by Cloudflare.
- If the errors are intermittent, it might be that the TCP connection between Cloudflare and your origin is being reset during the SSL handshake. Ask your hosting provider/system administrator to check if there are any server issues... [and check Cloudflare status].

Comment: I think the problem is not in a cloudflare.
Hetzner notified that the server was attacked and I think that this port scan is to blame for everything.
So, I block port scan, but traffic not disapear and some connections fails.